# mongoose schema inner join not getting result in my case

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

i am following many example of mongoose for inner join with schema but not getting response my other tables.
my question is what is missing in my code please help me this.

> i want getting result of class and subjects also.

```
  exports.classSubjectList = async (req, res, next) => {
  const obj = await ClassSubject.find().populate('classmodel').exec();
  res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        response: obj
      });
};
```

//ClassSubjectModel

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const classModel  = require('../class/classModel');
const subjectModel  = require('../subject/subjectModel');

var classsubject = new Schema({    
    ClassId: String,
    SubjectId : String,
    IsShow: { type: Boolean, default : true},   
    classmodel: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: classModel },
    subjectmodel: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: subjectModel },

});
```

//Class Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var classinfo = new Schema({    
    ClassName: String,
    IsShow: { type: Boolean, default : true},   

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('classinfo', classinfo);
```

//SUBJECT Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var subject = new Schema({    
    SubjectName: String,
    IsShow: Boolean,   

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('subject', subject);
```

result

```
[
        {
            "IsShow": true,
            "_id": "5e1efc0f354849246c472cfe",
            "SubjectId": "5e1da60bf52acb30b87e92c4",
            "ClassId": "5e1ec13ed777bf28d01e2481",          
            "__v": 0
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use model name instead of using file/object name in populate like as bellow.

```
exports.classSubjectList = async (req, res, next) => {
  const obj = await ClassSubject.find().populate('classinfo').exec();
  res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        response: obj
      });
};
```

//ClassSubjectModel

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const classModel  = require('../class/classModel');
const subjectModel  = require('../subject/subjectModel');

var classsubject = new Schema({    
    ClassId: String,
    SubjectId : String,
    IsShow: { type: Boolean, default : true},   
    classmodel: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: classinfo },
    subjectmodel: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: subjectModel },

});
```